# Msbuild compile website without placing the site in IIS

Tags: msbuild

I am trying to create a msbuild script that will compile and place a test app into a folder on my desktop. I do not want this app published to IIS. I have followed several blgos and looked through hashimi's book but I still cannot figure this out. Below is my script. Thank you very much!

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Clean">
    <ItemGroup>
      <BinFiles Include="bin\*.*" />

    </ItemGroup>
    <Delete Files="@(BinFiles)" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Compile" DependsOnTargets="Clean">
  <MSBuild Projects="test.vbproj"/>
  </Target>
  <Target Name="Publish" DependsOnTargets="Compile">
  <RemoveDir Directories="$(OutputFolder)" 
  ContinueOnError="true"/>
  <MSBuild Projects="test.vbproj"
            targets="ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication"
            Properties="WebProjectOutputdir=$(OutputFolder; OutDir=$WebProjectOutputDir)\"/>
            </Target>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is a bit awkward (you redefined the clean target to do the same as the the basic clean target).

I'm pretty sure your problem comes from the CopyWebApplication which does lots of stuff according to the properties set in your project file and pass by command line.

Can you try the following script :

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Compile" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Target Name="Compile">
    <MSBuild 
      Projects="test.vbproj"
      Targets="Clean;Build"
      Properties="OutputPath=C:\tmp"/>    
  </Target>
</Project>
```

if your test project is a website then the build target should create it on the folder specified in the OutputPath/OutDir property